# R Shiny, Centering Error message

Tags: css, r, shiny

How can I center the error message on R shiny?  Currently, I was trying with "text-align: center" like this:

```
error_message <- "  
.shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }  
.shiny-output-error:before {  
visibility: visible;  
margin: auto;  
text-align: center;
content: 'No results.'; }  
}  
"
```

But the error message still appears the top left corner. I wish to make it located in the center of the screen. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much at all about css, but last time I was trying to center align something in a shiny app I added `margin:auto; width:50%;` to get it to work. Forgot why...

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work on my error message...

Comment: I tried to find the documentation that led me to try that, it was somewhere in w3schools I think. The idea was that if the div takes up the whole width, then center align won't do anything. Shrinking the div to take up only half of the width makes it center (kinda). . . but, as I said, I don't really know what I'm talking about, which is why I'm not attempting an answer.